# IN operator to use AND operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on a report in SSRS which passes the result of one parameter to another parameter.

The first Parameter `@survey` is a list of surveys 
The second parameter `@question` is a list of questions

When the survey is select from `@survey` it populates `@question` with the list of questions on said survey using the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dimSurveyQuestion.QuestionID, dimSurveyQuestion.QuestionCaption,
                factSurveyResponseAnswer.SectionID, factSurveyResponseAnswer.DisplayOrder
FROM dimSurveyQuestion
INNER JOIN factSurveyResponseAnswer
    ON dimSurveyQuestion.QuestionID = factSurveyResponseAnswer.QuestionCaptionID
WHERE (factSurveyResponseAnswer.SurveyID IN (@Survey))
ORDER BY factSurveyResponseAnswer.SectionID,
         factSurveyResponseAnswer.DisplayOrder
```

The customer wishes to have the ability to select multiple surveys from the `@survey` parameter and then the `@question` parameter is populated with all of the questions which can be found in ALL of the surveys selected.

I understand that by using the `IN` Operator on my `WHERE` clause this will utilise the `OR` operator

So if the values `Survey1` and `Survey2` were selected in the `@survey` parameter the `WHERE` clause of the SQL is effectively saying:

```
WHERE (factSurveyResponseAnswer.SurveyID = Survey1 OR
       factSurveyResponseAnswer.SurveyID = Survey2)
```

Is there anyway in which I can pass multiple values through from the @survey Parameter and my `WHERE` clause to dynamically say:

```
 WHERE (factSurveyResponseAnswer.SurveyID = Survey1 AND
        factSurveyResponseAnswer.SurveyID = Survey2)
```

This would then bring back the questions which are present in both surveys.

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have searched the forum but was unable to find the answer.

Many Thanks

Comment: Think about it. The `WHERE` clause is always looking at the column values for an individual row. *no* row can ever, simultaneously, have `SurveyID` equal to two different values.

Comment: The most common solution to this type of thing is to pass a delimited list of SurveyIDs to your procedure. Then you need to split those strings inside your procedure. Here are a number of splitters. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings